# ESP8266 don't receive GET response from Node.js

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

i don't response from GET request, send from ESP8266 + Arduino Mega to Node.js. 
My code in node receive the request, but i don't get nothing in Arduino Code.

**Node.js**

```
app.get('/StatusSaidas', function(req,res){
    res.charset = 'UTF-8';
    console.log('Send to Arduino: ' + statusArdu);
    res.send(statusArdu);
});
```

**Console log from Node.js**

[image: Console.log Node.js]

Code in Arduino

```
  uint8_t buffer[1024] = {0};
  if (wifi.createTCP(HOST_NAME, HOST_PORT)) {
    Serial.print("Connection with Host OK!\r\n");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Error to connected to Host!\r\n");
  }
  char *ComandoGET = "GET /StatusSaidas HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: SmartHouse\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
  wifi.send((const uint8_t*)ComandoGET, strlen(ComandoGET));

  uint32_t len = wifi.recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 10000);
  char *resposta = buffer;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (strncmp(resposta++, "\r\n\r\n", 4) == 0) break;
  }
  resposta += 3;
  receive = resposta;
  Serial.print(receive);
  Serial.print("\n\r");
```

I don't know what is the problem with my code.
i Use ESP8266 with Arduino Mega

Comment: First, if you just do a `res.send` without also an `res.end` to end the response it might not finish sending the entire response correctly.  Second it looks like maybe you are trying to parse out HTTP headers from the response, but there are none because you are only sending `statusArdu`. Adding cookies to the response might just be causing the response to really contain `\r\n\r\n` which your code is specifically searching for, and that might be why it "works" with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in the line:

```
char *ComandoGET = "GET /StatusSaidas HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: SmartHouse\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

"SmartHouse" is probably not solved by your webserver. Your host should be something like Smarhouse.com or similar.

Comment: i found the problem. Its a cookies from my Node.js. When i have cookies in my project, ESP8266 can view the response. How i can fix that using this case?

Comment: what happens if you do a curl get to your nodejs server? Did you confirm that is everything ok with your webserver in first instance?

Comment: did you try to correct the host to the right value as I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Check this example: http://shawnhymel.com/695/quick-tip-http-get-with-the-esp8266-thing/

Comment: My host is local, i change to  'char *ComandoGET = "GET /StatusSaidas HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.0.101:5000\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";' and nothing...
When i use a Postaman to /StatusSaidas, its fine, send a data.
In this example, he uses ESP8266 alone, i use other library for Arduino, because i have Arduino Mega with ESP8266